# why should we use looking forward to seeing you instead of see you

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know that "looking forward to" is followed by a gerund but 
I do not know why should we use a gerund like seeing and meeting instead of the infinitives like see and meet.

Is it a matter of grammar, or usage?

Comment: Perhaps you think because there's a 'to' there is should be the infinitive. But 'to' here isn't part of an infinitive. It's a preposition.

Comment: LIke most "why" questions about language, the answer is "Because that's how the language is". _Looking forward_ does not take a direct object, whether it is an infinitive or anything else: it takes and indirect object with _to_, and accepts a gerund not an infinitive.

Comment: how can we know that  to is a part of infinitive?

Comment: I have tried to remove them but in vain.It must be edited

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Answer

in the form "looking forward to seeing you" we are trying to emphasis that we will be glad to actually see you (in the future; at a specific, but not specified time). ie an event that has not been completed yet As opposed to emphasis on the whole looking forward to the meeting scenario.

The whole choice of words revolves around emphasis. In spoken English "See you later" is casual. "I will see you later" is more definite, even demanding dependant on tone of voice. "I will be seeing you later" can be even more dominant.
In writing we have to find other ways to emphasis.

Seeing Grammar [enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see?q=seeing)

**Seeing: Grammar**
Hear, see, etc. + object + infinitive or -ing
We can use either the infinitive without to or the -ing form after the object of verbs such as hear, see, notice, watch. **The infinitive without to often emphasises the whole action or event which someone hears or sees. The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event which is in progress or not yet completed.** …

Comment: I find the answer confusing. 'I saw him come/coming in' (an example of the grammar you describe) is not the same syntax pattern as 'I look forward to seeing you'.

Comment: The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event which is in progress or not yet completed. …Is"'I saw him come" or  'I saw him coming in' a past. present or future tense? saw verb UK ​  /sɔː/ US ​  /sɑː/ past simple of see

Comment: My point is that it doesn't seem to be an answer to the question as I understand it, which is: Why is it grammatically incorrect to say 'I'm looking forward to see you'.

Comment: Where does the question or my answer say "Why is it grammatically incorrect to say 'I'm looking forward to see you'.  The question says "Is it a matter of grammar or usage?" My answer explains why we would use" to seeing you" instead of "see you" I have not said either is incorrect only when we would use them.

Comment: @Brad.Yout  answer gives the impression that both looking forward to see  you and seeing you are correct, probably with a shade of difference in meanimg I hope you wil explain it      further

Comment: It is more subtle than meaning, it is the emphasis giving the impression of how important the writer thinks seeing them is!

Comment: At a second look, it's probably the wording of the question that makes it ambiguous. I read it as "Why should we use looking forward to seeing you instead of [looking forward] to see you?" And I think you were comparing "looking forward to seeing you" with the phrase "See you!"

Comment: what exactly is the difference between I  am looking forward to seeing you and I am looking forward to see you

Comment: In the first the grammar is correct, in the second it is not.

Comment: This site might help. https://www.grammaring.com/preposition-gerund

Comment: 1. "He thought **of** go to college but he changed his mind" OR "He thought **of** going to college but he changed his mind" 2. "They were talking **about** see the movie" OR "They were talking **about** seeing a movie." 3. "I'm good **at** play tennis" OR "I'm good **at** playing tennis" 4. "She is used **to** drink tea" OR "She is used **to** drinking tea" None of the *grammatical* instances (preposition + V+ING) are *..in progress or not yet completed…*